# Push local traffic "outside" the nat

Tags: nat, iptables

I have a server functioning as my nat that hosts some services. When I locally connect via UDP to this server it my client uses the public ip but the server answers with its local ip.

So the question is: How can I force all traffic that is directed to the public ip to be routed through the NAT too?

Or is there some even simpler method to achieve the conversation taking place on the public ip (without letting the traffic "leak" out into the public)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `MASQUERADE` rule for this traffic on the nat box. This makes it so that traffic to any of the DNAT services will appear to come from the nat box. That way when the DNAT service replies, the traffic goes back to the nat box so it can be properly sent back to the client (with the correct source IP address).

For example, if your private network were `192.168.0.0/24` and the nat box has this network on `eth1`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

(You could use SNAT instead of MASQUERADE, either works)